# Freezing enemies and unfreezing them in a Infinity Runner game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a game which generates infinite level blocks, and there's always 3 blocks instanced, the problem is that these level blocks have enemies that move, and sometimes the player is too slow or too fast and the enemies are in a position that they shouldn't be (like falling into the player and killing him instantly).

The solution I thought is to freeze each added block (the last one int the list of current instanced blocks), and when the player goes to the next block, unfreeze it, so the enemies start to move as soon as the player enters the block, not when it is generated.

Here are the functions that freeze and unfreeze:

```
public void UnfreezeCurrentLevelBlockEnemies()
{
    if(currentBlocks.Count == 3)
    {
        foreach (Rigidbody2D enemy in currentBlocks[1].transform)
        {
            enemy.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
            Debug.Log("I'm in index 1 levelblock freezing" );
        }
    } else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Generating initial blocks, blocks will not be 
        frozen yet...");
    }

}

public void FreezeLastLevelBlockEnemies()
{
    if (currentBlocks.Count == 3)
    {
        foreach (Rigidbody2D enemy in currentBlocks[2].transform)
        {
            enemy.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
            Debug.Log("I'm in index 2 levelblock freezing" );
        }
    } else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Generating initial blocks, blocks will not be 
        frozen yet...");
    }
}
```

How can I freeze all the enemies and unfreeze them properly?

I want to freeze the enemies (birds and mouses) and this is the level block structure:

[image]

Video of the game so you understand better the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXzOoEbo0Aw&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, just in case someone had my problem here is how you can freeze enemies:

```
public void FreezeLevelBlockEnemies(int index)
{
    if (currentBlocks.Count == 3 && freezeEnemiesOutOfCurrentBlock)
    {
        foreach (MouseMovement enemy in currentBlocks[index].GetComponentsInChildren<MouseMovement>())
        {
            enemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
            Debug.Log("I'm in " + index + " index levelblock freezing");
        }
        foreach (BirdMovement enemy in currentBlocks[index].GetComponentsInChildren<BirdMovement>())
        {
            enemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
            Debug.Log("I'm in " + index + " index levelblock freezing");
        }
    } else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Freeze is disabled");
    }
}
```